# What does the connect command do when using Mongoose (using it in a node.js environment)?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm new to mongoose and am having trouble starting out. All I want to do is store some values, and retrieve all values. Right now, I'm just trying to get a base example working. Here's my code right now:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var IPhoneDevice = new Schema({
    fbId  :  { type: String }
  , deviceToken   :  { type: String }
});

var IPhone = db.model('IPhone', IPhoneDevice);

var u = new IPhone();
u.fbId = 'John';
u.save(function(){
    log.debug("Saving");
});

IPhone.find({}).all(function(array){
    log.debug("Finding stuff");
});
```

The problem is, it never prints out anything. I think it might be something to do with the mongoose connect line. I just copied this from an example, but does there need to be a file on my localhost where the database is stored? I don't have any file called my_database anywhere...do I need to create one?

Answer (score 0):

I would write the last call like this:

```
IPhone.find({}, function (err, docs) {
   console.log(docs);
});
```

mongoose needs the query in the find, then a callback to handle the returned documents or the error.

See: [Finding Document with Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/finding-documents.html)

Comment: is your program exiting before it prints out something ?
or otherwise, log.debug does not work for me, I had to use console.log instead.

Comment: I changed the program to do console.log instead, and also added a simple 'hello world' server so the program wouldn't exit, but still no luck. The program definitely isn't running the callback function because even if I put garbage there, the program doesn't crash...

Comment: Ok, so actually I've worked it out. I wasn't running a mongodb on my local machine so it had nothing to connect to. Thanks for your help.